# Jquery how to show / hide a series of div when they all use same classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting with dynamic mark up a series of div that all use same classes. They all come with a show/hide link but with no functionality whatsoever.

I need to add show/hide functionality for each div. Reading answers from this same comunity I cant find a way of doing this when the elements to hide have all the same class.

All my aproach ither show or hide the divs all at once.

Comment: It would be easier for us to help if you provided the general structure of the markup you get, and the attempt(s) you've made so far.

Comment: post your html and jquery please.

Comment: you want hide and show indivisually or wt?

Answer (score 0):

it depends of the actual markup, but this might work:

```
$(this).closest(".myClass").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will either show or hide div's of same class when you will click on a div.

```
$(this).click(function(){
 var div1Class = $(this).attr('class');
 $(div1Class).toggle(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a series of divs which I want to hide on mouseover and show on mouseout. So I put them in a div called container and used the following to implement it. Hope it helps you.

```
function showHide(div){
    div.onmouseover = function(){
        div.style.display = "none";
    };
    div.onmouseout = function(){
        div.style.display = "";
    };
}


var divList = document.getElementById('container').children;
for(var i = 0 ; i < divList.length; i++){
    var div = divList[i];
    showHide(div);
}
```